# JSTL Pagination for Map inside Map

Tags: servlets, jdbc, collections, pagination, jstl

I need to Implement simple pagination displaying 100 records per page and pagination data is sorted by date.Though I have sorted the information correctly,however I am unable to think about pagination logic since resultset is inside map which is again holding Map inside it,

Below is my JSTL Code along with definition for TitleList/Title which I am iterating after adding resultset data in it.

```
 Map<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> TitleList = new LinkedHashMap<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>();

LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> Title = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

<c:forEach items="${TitleList}" var="column"> 
            <p><c:out value="${column.key}"/></p>                      
            <c:forEach var="Title" items="${column.value}">
                <p><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Test.do?id=${Title.key}"><c:out value="${Title.value}"/></a></p>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
```

Though I can paginate it by adding resultset directly to list ,however that will kill by sorting order and functionality I am looking for.Somehow for above code, I need to restrict the 100 records per page and then implement Next button which will again display 100 records.
Appreciate some thoughts on this.

Updated:Adding more information,this is how map looks like from servlet where I am creating titlelist and title maps,

```
map = {2012-07-12={160=tstng, 159=testing}, 2012-07-10={158=test, 157=test, 156=Testing, 155=Testing, 154=Testing, 153=Testing, 152=Testing, 151=Testing, 150=Testing, 149=Testing, 148=Testing, 147=Testing, 146=Testing, 145=Testing, 144=Testing, 143=Testing, 142=Testing, 141=Teasting, 140=Teasting, 139=Testing, 138=Testing, 137=Testing , 136=Testing for testing, 135=Testing for testing, 134=Testing for Test, 133=Testing}, 2012-07-04={132=Testing for Broker}, 2012-07-03={131=Testing for Post, 130=1200 TESTIN}, 2012-07-01={129=testing}, 2012-03-30={128=upload test}, 2012-03-28={127=test}, 2012-01-08={126=1BHK flat for 1000$ at Journal Square}, 2012-01-04={125=tseting by kiran, 124=tseting by kiran, 123=tseting by kiran, 122=tseting by kiran, 121=tseting by kiran, 120=tseting by kiran, 119=tseting by kiran, 118=tseting by kiran, 117=tseting by kiran, 116=tseting by kiran, 115=tseting by kiran, 114=tseting by kiran, 113=tseting by kiran, 112=tseting by kiran, 111=tseting by kiran, 110=tseting by kiran, 109=tseting by kiran, 108=tseting by kiran, 107=tseting by kiran, 106=tseting by kiran, 105=tseting by kiran, 104=tseting by kiran}, 2012-01-02={103=testing, 102=testing, 101=testing, 100=testing, 99=testing, 98=testing, 97=testing, 96=testing, 95=testing, 94=testing, 93=testing, 92=testing, 91=testing, 90=testing, 89=testing, 88=testing, 87=testing, 86=testing, 85=testing, 84=testing, 83=testing, 82=testing, 81=testing, 80=testing, 79=testing, 78=testing, 77=testing, 76=testing, 75=testing, 74=testing}, 2011-12-09={73=The monthly consumer price index rose 4.2% from the year-ago period, reflecting a huge easing from Octoberâ??s 5.5% increase. }, 2011-12-08={72=Testing for dispplay}, 2011-11-25={71=Apartment for Rent at Journal Square for 1000$.Please see now., 70=Apartment for Rent at Journal Square for 1000$.Please see now., 69=testing, 68=AS, 67=A, 66=A, 65=q, 64=q, 63=Testing, 62=Testing}, 2011-11-24={61=testing, 60=tEST, 59=TESTING, 58=TESTING, 57=Testing, 56=Testing, 55=Testing, 54=tseting, 53=testing, 52=testing, 51=testing, 50=teting, 49=tESTING, 48=tESTING, 47=tESTING, 46=Testing, 45=TESTING, 44=TESTING, 43=tESTING}, 2011-11-23={42=Testing, 41=testing, 40=Testing, 39=tESTING, 38=TETING, 37=testing}, 2011-11-22={36=Testing, 35=Testing, 34=Testing, 33=Testing by Kiran, 32=testing, 31=Testing, 30=Testing by Kiran, 29=Testing byt kiran, 28=Testing by Kiran, 27=testing by kiran, 26=testing by kiran, 25=Testing , 24=TSETING, 23=Testing by Kiran}, 2011-11-21={22=testing, 21=Testng, 20=TESTING, 19=TESTING, 18=ESTING, 17=ESTING, 16=ESTING, 15=ESTING, 14=testing by kiran, 13=testing by Kiran, 12=Testing by Kiran, 11=testing by Kiran, 10=Testing by Kian, 9=Testing by Kiran, 8=Testing by Kiran, 7=Testing byKiran, 6=testing, 5=Test by Kiran, 4=Test by Kiran}, 2011-11-20={3=testing, 2=testing, 1=testing}}
```

Below is servlet code I which will create map after reading from DB,

```
 Map<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> TitleList = new LinkedHashMap<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>();
            String sqld = "Select Distinct DATE(timestamp) as DATE from table ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 730 ;";
            ResultSet rsd = null;
            try {
                rsd = stmt1.executeQuery(sqld);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(myclass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                while (rsd.next()) {
                    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> Title = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
            //        System.out.println("Testing");
                    Date Date = rsd.getDate("Date");
            //        System.out.println(Date);
                    String sql = "Select title,id from table Where DATE(timestamp) = '" + Date + "'ORDER BY id DESC";
           //         System.out.println(sql);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    rs.last();
                    int numRows = rs.getRow();
          //          System.out.println(rs.getRow());
                    rs.beforeFirst();
                    while (rs.next()) {                                  
                        for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
                            String title = rs.getString("title");
                            Integer id = rs.getInt("id");
                               Title.put(id, title);                         
                            TitleList.put(Date, Title);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Size of LinkedHashMap for Title  : " + Title.size());
         //               System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));
                    }

                }
```

here is something I tried Richz,
Here is what I am getting in dao class I did something like below,

```
string query ="select title,id,date(timestamp) as date from table";
list<TitleList> list = new ArrayList<Titlelist>(); 
try {

 resultset rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next()){
     myclass myc = new myclass();
     myc.setcid(rs.getInt("id");
     myc.settitle(rs.getString("title");
     myc.settimestamp(rs.gettimestamp("timestamp");
     list.add(myc);
    }
```

and in jsp

```
<c:foreach var="Titlelist" items="${Titlelist}">
  EL for title,id and title
</c:foreach>
With this approach I can do pagination date wise along pages and data looks like below along with pagination

Date10 title10
Date10 title09



However I need data in this format,
Date 10
title10
title09
```

I tried doing list of lists but for some reasons I am unable to do it.I am losing relations between columns.My internet search shows me pagination as done above for list.

Updated Details on 31st August,

Ok Richz here is my JSP, I have used exactly the same structure as yours.

```
<%@page import="java.util.LinkedHashMap"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/header.jsp" %>
<%@ include file="WEB-INF/jspf/navdisplay.jspf" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page session="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DB Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="dateTotal" scope="session" value="${fn:length(list)}"/>
        <c:set var="currentDate" value="${param.date}"/>
        <c:if test="${empty currentDate or currentDate < 0}">
            <c:set var="currentDate" value="0"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${dateTotal <= currentDate}">
            <c:set var="currentDate" value="${dateTotal - 1}"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="10"/>
        <c:set var="pageStart" value="${param.start}"/>
        <c:if test="${empty pageStart or pageStart < 0}">
            <c:set var="pageStart" value="0"/>
        </c:if>
        <a href="?date=${currentDate - 1}">Previous Date</a>  <a  href="?date=${currentDate + 1}">Next Date</a><br/>
        Titles <a href="?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + perPage} <a  href="?start=${pageStart + perPage}">>></a>
        <c:forEach items="${list[currentDate]}" var="item" > 
            <p><c:out value="${item.key}"/></p> 
            <c:forEach var="Title" items="${item.value}" begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}" >
                <p><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Test.do?id=${Title.key}"><c:out value="${Title.value}"/></a></p>   
            </c:forEach>                  
        </c:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is servlet which is generating data for list,

List list = new ArrayList();

```
    Map<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> TitleList = new LinkedHashMap<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>();
    String sqld = "Select Distinct DATE(ctimestamp) as DATE from table ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 730 ;";
    ResultSet rsd = null;
    try {
        rsd = stmt1.executeQuery(sqld);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(sortResultshs.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        while (rsd.next()) {
            LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> Title = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    //        System.out.println("Testing");
            Date Date = rsd.getDate("Date");
   //         System.out.println(Date);

            String sql = "Select title,id from table Where DATE(ctimestamp) = '" + Date + "'ORDER BY id DESC";
    //        System.out.println(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.last();
            int numRows = rs.getRow();
  //          System.out.println(rs.getRow());
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                //        List<String> Title = new ArrayList<String>();               
                for (int i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
                    String title = rs.getString("title");
                    Integer id = rs.getInt("id");
                    Title.put(id, title);
                    TitleList.put(Date, Title);                         

                }

 //               System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));
            }

             list.add(TitleList);

        }
```

and the list looks something like below,

Total Row count is  : 160
List is  : [{2012-07-12={160=tstng, 159=testing}, 2012-07-10={158=test, 157=test, 156=Testing, 155=Testing, 154=Testing, 153=Testing, 152=Testing, 151=Testing, 150=Testing, 149=Testing, 148=Testing, 147=Testing, 146=Testing, 145=Testing, 144=Testing, 143=Testing, 142=Testing, 141=Teasting, 140=Teasting, 139=Testing, 138=Testing, 137=Testing , 136=Testing for testing, 135=Testing for testing, 134=Testing for Test, 133=Testing}, 2012-07-04={132=Testing for Broker}, 2012-07-03={131=Testing for Post, 130=1200 TESTIN}, 2012-07-01={129=testing}, 2012-03-30={128=upload test}, 2012-03-28={127=test}, 2012-01-08={126=1BHK flat for 1000$ at Journal Square}, 2012-01-04={125=tseting by kiran, 124=tseting by kiran, 123=tseting by kiran, 122=tseting by kiran, 121=tseting by kiran, 120=tseting by kiran, 119=tseting by kiran, 118=tseting by kiran, 117=tseting by kiran, 116=tseting by kiran, 115=tseting by kiran, 114=tseting by kiran, 113=tseting by kiran, 112=tseting by kiran, 111=tseting by kiran, 110=tseting by kiran, 109=tseting by kiran, 108=tseting by kiran, 107=tseting by kiran, 106=tseting by kiran, 105=tseting by kiran, 104=tseting by kiran}, 2012-01-02={103=testing, 102=testing, 101=testing, 100=testing, 99=testing, 98=testing, 97=testing, 96=testing, 95=testing, 94=testing, 93=testing, 92=testing, 91=testing, 90=testing, 89=testing, 88=testing, 87=testing, 86=testing, 85=testing, 84=testing, 83=testing, 82=testing, 81=testing, 80=testing, 79=testing, 78=testing, 77=testing, 76=testing, 75=testing, 74=testing}, 2011-12-09={73=The monthly consumer price index rose 4.2% from the year-ago period, reflecting a huge easing from Octoberâ??s 5.5% increase. }, 2011-12-08={72=Testing for dispplay}, 2011-11-25={71=Apartment for Rent at Journal Square for 1000$.Please see now., 70=Apartment for Rent for 1000$.Please see now., 69=testing, 68=AS, 67=A, 66=A, 65=q, 64=q, 63=Testing, 62=Testing}, 2011-11-24={61=testing, 60=tEST, 59=TESTING, 58=TESTING, 57=Testing, 56=Testing, 55=Testing, 54=tseting, 53=testing, 52=testing, 51=testing, 50=teting, 49=tESTING, 48=tESTING, 47=tESTING, 46=Testing, 45=TESTING, 44=TESTING, 43=tESTING}, 2011-11-23={42=Testing, 41=testing, 40=Testing, 39=tESTING, 38=TETING, 37=testing}, 2011-11-22={36=Testing, 35=Testing, 34=Testing, 33=Testing by Kiran, 32=testing, 31=Testing, 30=Testing by Kiran, 29=Testing byt kiran, 28=Testing by Kiran, 27=testing by kiran, 26=testing by kiran, 25=Testing , 24=TSETING, 23=Testing by Kiran}, 2011-11-21={22=testing, 21=Testng, 20=TESTING, 19=TESTING, 18=ESTING, 17=ESTING, 16=ESTING, 15=ESTING, 14=testing by kiran, 13=testing by Kiran, 12=Testing by Kiran, 11=testing by Kiran, 10=Testing by Kian, 9=Testing by Kiran, 8=Testing by Kiran, 7=Testing byKiran, 6=testing, 5=Test by Kiran, 4=Test by Kiran}, 2011-11-20={3=testing, 2=testing, 1=testing}}]

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I assume you are retreiving all the records from the DB and now you want to sort it and display only 100 records at a time on the page. To solve this issue you can you following approach

1. Store the result in a master Array List. Then use public List subList(int fromIndex,
   int toIndex) to extract the first 100 records and store this data in to the request scope and use it in the jsp as mentioned above
2. When user clicks on Next button, use the master arraylist and now fetch the next set of 100 records and display the page again with the new set of records. Make sure you maintain a variable which has the count of the startIndex of the current records.

Doing pagination in this way might have performance hit if you have a big list as this list will then need to be stored in the session for subsequent request from same user.

Comment: I can experiment with try this Approach and see how results I get.For some of the functionality, I have expect list to be big enough.

Comment: I also do not retrive all the data at one go, this is how I do it,I first run the query with distinct clause to get distinct dates, these distinct dates are stored in Date list, and then use these dates to fire another query which will give me title and id, this title and id are then fed to the linkedhash map.and finally I add all those thing in another linkedhashmap.

Comment: Rickz, this is what I finally did and which solved my problem,

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hiding-the-element-after-doing-some-comparison#14737000003576557

Answer (score 0):

Please try this demo page.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
  //dummy data
  List<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();
  long now = new Date().getTime();
  for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
     LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> titleMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
     for(int j = 1; j < 43 ;j++){
         titleMap.put(j, "title" + j);
     }
     Map<Date, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>> dateMap = new LinkedHashMap<Date,    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>();
     dateMap.put(new Date(now + 1000*60*60*25* i), titleMap);
     list.add(dateMap);
 }
 pageContext.setAttribute("list", list);
%>
<c:set var="dateTotal" scope="session" value="${fn:length(list)}"/>
<c:set var="currentDate" value="${param.date}"/>
<c:if test="${empty currentDate or currentDate < 0}">
    <c:set var="currentDate" value="0"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${dateTotal <= currentDate}">
    <c:set var="currentDate" value="${dateTotal - 1}"/>
</c:if>
<c:set var="perPage" scope="session"  value="10"/>
<c:set var="pageStart" value="${param.start}"/>
<c:if test="${empty pageStart or pageStart < 0}">
    <c:set var="pageStart" value="0"/>
</c:if>
<a href="?date=${currentDate - 1}">Previous Date</a>  <a  href="?date=${currentDate + 1}">Next Date</a><br/>
Titles <a href="?start=${pageStart - perPage}"><<</a>${pageStart + 1} - ${pageStart + perPage} <a  href="?start=${pageStart + perPage}">>></a>
<c:forEach items="${list[currentDate]}" var="item" > 
     <p><c:out value="${item.key}"/></p> 
     <c:forEach var="Title" items="${item.value}" begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}" >
          <p><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Test.do?id=${Title.key}"><c:out value="${Title.value}"/></a></p>   
     </c:forEach>                  
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it loops too many times for column.key and column values.Something goes wrong with that for each tag.

Comment: {TitleList} is map inside map for which items looks something like {2012/07/02,{{1,title1}{2,title2},{3,title3}},so when I use foreach tag and try to loop titlelist value field, it goes crazy.

Comment: I thought that TitleList was a map that whose keys are dates and values are maps. What does ${fn:length(TitleList)} print ? Maybe we should work with some dummy data to test the JSTL ?

Comment: I am checking Rickz.Will update this again.Just give me sometime

Comment: Ok its printing 18 and maybe thats reason as why its not pagination.However I have more than 100 records in the value part of the map.Each date can have more than 100 records and this part I need to paginate and if date has less 100 records and then it should be paginate both date and its asociated values.

Comment: Second code, still displays all records in first page in 1 to 100 link and then from 100 to 200 link, it displays all keys of Titlelist.This is becoming really interesting problem for me.

Comment: I will try this and let you know rickz.

Comment: Just now I ran your updated code Richz, it does not honour the perpage variable,for each date, its printing 10 titles in all 30 titles in the page,where the requirement is to print 10 titles per page and paginate it until the totalCount.

Comment: Data structure I have is dynamic,for each date, I might have 5 titles or 200 titles and its pagination should display 100 titles if they are available for that date and paginate the rest to the next page.If the dates have less than 100 titles as their values,then they should display 100 titles along with respective dates and then paginate both date and respective titles to next page.

Comment: Give me sometime I will post the piece of code and the way I am generating datastructure,it might give some more clarity.

Comment: I have added some more info richz.Please see if you can think of something.inner map is dynamic and per page for this should be 100.

Comment: I am sorry. I was away from my desktop for a few days. If I understand your problem correctly, then I would change your data structure. I would make TitleList a list of lists and not a map of maps. That way you could have pagination the way you have described it. Do you want me to post demo code?

Comment: Richz, can you give me some demo logic with lists of lists.I tried in many ways but its not coming the way I need it.I have updated the main code, the way I was able to do it with lists.But this is not my requirement.

Comment: Please try my latest demo page.

Comment: No Rickz its not working and not following 10 records per page logic.What I am looking for is craglist style pagination.http://newjersey.craigslist.org/apa/  Please do look at this link.Its showing titles per date and for each date is showing 100 records per page if they exists else its its looks like this http://newjersey.craigslist.org/bus/ . Seems like I have rework on data structure again and think something other way.

Comment: Did you copy and paste my page as I posted it ? It works for me.

Comment: Yes Richz, your code as it is works for me as well.Its just that when I replace it with my resultset data, its not working.It displays all the records in the first page.and I did ensure that datastructure looks similar to as your.Let me try again

Comment: <c:set var="currentDate" value="${param.date}"/>  This is one which is giving me null whenever I replace the list backend data.Is their a way where I just pull the dates from the DateMap List.Adding as it is will lead it to cast exception.

Comment: It should be null until you click on one of the links(Previous or Next Date) that send a value for date. Please bear in mind that the variables are Strings. That is what is sent in the query string of the links. When currentDate is null(empty), the conditional sets it to "0". That way the first Date in the list will displayed.

Comment: <c:forEach var="Title" items="${item.value}" begin="${pageStart}" end="${pageStart + perPage - 1}" >
          <p><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Test.do?id=${Title.key}"><c:out value="${Title.value}"/></a></p>   
     </c:forEach>

Comment: The above code is problematic, here is why for the first date when it iterates and if it has 5 values it displays five value and now when second date has say about 105,it stops at 100 ignoring the initial 5 values and then displays 105 in the page ignoring the perpage flag.

Comment: Sorry had some other issues so cannot reply back Richz.

Comment: I don't why you are having a problem with the perPage value. It works in my demo code. Perhaps you can post a JSP of your own that demonstrates the problem. Just use dummy data. I don't have a database to test.

Comment: Ok Rickz I have added details about jsp.If you look closely at list output, you can see that some dates have more values than per page and in such cases,and in some cases less than per page.So when inner for each loop iterates, it sticks to per page value per iteration that it per element.Let me see if I can add a screenshot to show you the output as how it looks like.

Comment: this is what I did finally Richz,http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hiding-the-element-after-doing-some-comparison#14737000003576557